# How use hash tag ("a name") to go to spot on page but account for a fixed element at top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the site, there is a menu bar at the top which is `position: fixed` and is `height: 4em;`. When I click a hash link `<a href="#someName">go to</a>`, it moves the page to place the `<a name="someName"></a>` at the top of the window, which means it is underneath the top bar, and partially hidden. How do I account for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/x3gr8s8z/

HTML:

```
<div class="topbar"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a href="#link">click me</a>
<a name="link"></a>
Going to here
```

CSS:

```
.topbar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: @torazaburo how do I do that?

Comment: HTML5 note: `<a name=...>` is no longer valid use in HTML5 ([the `name` attribute no longer exists on the `a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a)). It'll work, because browsers love to be backward compatible, but it's not how you do things anymore. Under HTML5 rules you use an element's `id` attribute now, so something with `href="#abc"` navigates to things `<element id="abc">`, not a named anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trap the hashchange event and scroll the window down by the height of the fixed element.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, -40);
});
```

Instead of 40, you could use

```
document.querySelector('.topbar').getClientBoundingRect().height
```

Comment: `getClienBoundingRect`?

Comment: I think you mean `-40`.